# How to edit this php function to use different templates based on value?

Tags: php

This code below currently just rotate flags to load different templates based on count. But I want to make use flag 1 for Sell if its not null or otherwise Flag 2 for Buy ?

How I can do that?

```
    $content = '';
    $flag = 1;
    while ($row = $db->doRead())
    {
        $content .= Template::Load('market-' . $flag++, 
            array
            (
                'name' => $row['UserID'], 
                'buy' => $row['Buy'],
                'sell' => $row['Sell'],
                'Item' => $row['Item'],
                'Item2' => $row['Item2']
            )
        );
        if ($flag > 2) $flag = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$row['Sell']` is NULL, and set `$flag` accordingly:

```
if (! is_null($row['Sell'])) {
   $flag = 1;
}
else {
   $flag = 2;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt want to display correctly. if there are 3 rows, it display only those with SELL (2) the other one is not displayed since its BUY but If I second Buy, it display total of 3 rows but its NULL instead of Buy. So only Sell is displayed correctly. What may cause that?

Comment: It's impossible to know from the code you have provided. You would need to provide a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but this should work:

```
    $content = '';
    while ($row = $db->doRead())
    {
        $flag = $row['Sell']?1:2;
        $content .= Template::Load('market-' . $flag, 
            array
            (
                'name' => $row['UserID'], 
                'buy' => $row['Buy'],
                'sell' => $row['Sell'],
                'Item' => $row['Item'],
                'Item2' => $row['Item2']
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt work. it display the buy value as NULL since its counted as sell but what may cause that?